# How to add a new button to the button bar in Total Commander for Android?

Tags: file-management

I got Total Commander on my Android phone.

I need to check the directory size for a folder and the solution is:

[Add a new button to the button bar, and then](https://www.ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?t=40283)..

I understand that but my question is how to add a new button to the button bar?

Comment: This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: I don't understand. The help center says I can ask questions about software on this site. This question is not about programming. There is an entire tag on this site for questions like this one - https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/total-commander - But anyways, where do you think I can ask this question then?

Comment: Question about Android devices and software that runs on the Android OS are out of scope.  The tag you used should only be used if your asking about the Windows client

Comment: Ahh right! Sorry! I will ask it on the Android site. My bad, apologizes. I will mark it for deletion. Thanks